# Interaction between fluid flow and elastic obstacle (fluid-structure interaction)

Tags: differential-equations, finite-element-method, fluid-dynamics

I would like to model the velocity and pressure distribution of an elastic obstacle in a channel where the fluid flows. There are Navier-Stokes examples in Mathematica webpage with rigid obstacles but couldn't find anything related to elastic deformation of the obstacle.

I found a 2-D example in Elmer manual and would like to repeat the same in Mathematica:

*The channel is assumed to be 2D. The length of the channel is 10 m and the height is 2 m. At the distance of 2 m from the inlet sits an elastic beam with a rounded top the height of which is 1.2 m and width 0.4 m. A parabolic velocity profile with maximum velocity of 1 m/s is assumed.*

*Material properties are assumed to be rather simple: For the structure the density is 1000 kg/m3, Young’s modulus is 1000 Pa, and Poisson ratio 0.3. For the fluid the density is 1 kg/m3 and viscosity is 0.1 Pas. Additionally the fluid has elastic properties that are used to extend the displacement of the elastic beam to the fluid.*

Any guidance is highly appreciated.

[image]

[image]

[image]

Comment: Three close votes and not a single comment on why? Hi metudust, welcome to MmaSE. The community will be considering closing this question arguing that _"it cannot be answered without additional information"_, which is fair, as you have just pasted a hard problem without showing any code you have tried so far.  I recommend you edit your question promptly or it will be closed.

Comment: Start by earning the informed badge by taking the [tour] now. As it stands, nobody will answer your question, make a reasonable attempt to write [an excellent question](https://goo.gl/BqKxV3). Always [Edit](https://goo.gl/ELLhTX) if improvable, show due diligence, give brief context, include **minimal working example** of code and data in **[formatted form](https://goo.gl/ELLhTX)**. Show you can solve a simpler problem and highlight what is stopping you to take the necessary steps to solve the harder problem.